# Android - Storing information in a configuration manager?

Tags: android, configuration

So I'm trying to store some configuration values such as serviceUrl in a file, instead of hard-coding it in my code?

- Where is the proper place to store this information?
- Does android have some sort of configuration manager, or am I suppose to write my own config class that reads needed info from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `java.util.properties` along with `AssetManager` in andorid to read a properties file from `assets` directory.

**AssetManager:** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

**Properties:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

You should used the SharedPreferences data store to save the configuration data. SharedPreferences support all the atomic Java types for read and write, e.g. String for your service URI.

Here is more information on SharedPreferences and on alternative data stores: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html